# Ubuntu Software Center and VM

Tags: 12.04, software-center, virtualization

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my system after 20 years of windows.  I also installed it on a virtual machine.  I have noticed that Ubuntu restricted extras in the regular system are different from the virtual machine.  Is this OK?

Image 1 is Ubuntu 12.04 running inside a Virtual Machine 
[image]

Image 2 is Ubuntu 12.04 running  from PC 
[image]

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I never had this help this fast from my previous OS maker

Comment: thats very interesting, looks like the first one isn't getting all the add-ons.

Comment: [Matthew's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/130275/3940) is correct. It may depend on a different architecture. Is one of your systems 32-bit, the other 64-bit?

Comment: Here's the related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/833650

Comment: both are 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual install of ubuntu-restricted-extras should be fine, try installing it first, for the add-ons, it looks like there is a bug in not listing them, they still should be available if you search for the names individually in synaptic package manager. For Adobe Flash plugin search for the name in parenthesis , flashplugin-installer , ect.

Comment: +1 I just tested this: only after you installed the restricted extras all will be listed (many more than in the list)  ;)